# Proving directly that $\aleph_{\alpha+1} \cdot \aleph_{\alpha+1} = \aleph_{\alpha+1}$ by recursion

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I have defined the alephs by induction : $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is by definition the smallest cardinal superior to $\aleph_{\alpha}.$
Is there a quick way to show that $\aleph_{\alpha+1} \cdot \aleph_{\alpha+1} = \aleph_{\alpha+1}$ assuming that $\aleph_{\alpha} \cdot \aleph_{\alpha} = \aleph_{\alpha}$ ?

Comment: See Jech Set Theory (2006) Theorem 3.5 or Kunen Set Theory (2013) Theorem I.11.6.

Comment: I don't see how, to be honest.